# Allure MS Test Framework: Issue while generating the report

Tags: report, allure

I am getting the below error while generating report through command line report generation tool.

> Exception in thread "main" ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.ReportGenerationExcepti on: Could not find any allure results at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureRe portGenerator.java:58) at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureRe portGenerator.java:53) at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.AllureMain.main(AllureMain.java:48)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the Allure results directory to commandline to generate the report, an example:

```
$ allure generate allure-results -o allure-report
```

Allure results directory is the directory which contains `*-testsuite.xml` files. Make sure your `C:\TestResults\file.xml/` directory contains at least one such file.